# Pad sequence to multiple of a number TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I want to pad a sequence in Tensorflow to multiple of a number. The code I have tried is:

```
import tensorflow as tf
def pad_to_multiple(tensor, multiple, dim=-1, value=0):
    seqlen = tf.shape(tensor)[dim]
    seqlen = tf.cast(seqlen, tf.float32)
    multiple = tf.cast(multiple, tf.float32)
    m = seqlen / multiple
    if tf.math.equal(tf.math.floor(m), m):
        return False, tensor
    remainder = tf.math.ceil(m) * multiple - seqlen
    paddings = tf.zeros([tf.rank(tensor), 2], dtype=tf.int32)
    paddings = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(paddings, tf.reshape([dim, 1], [1, 2]), tf.reshape([remainder, 0], [1, 2]))
    tensor = tf.pad(tensor, paddings, constant_values=value)
    return True, tensor
```

It throws the following error at `tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update`:

```
Inner dimensions of output shape must match inner dimensions of updates shape. Output: [4,2] updates: [1,2]
```

Is there a way I can fix this dimension mismatch in `tensor_scatter_nd_update`?

Answer (score 1):

There is dimension mismatch it is why throwing error

Try the below and see if it fixes the issue:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def pad_to_multiple(tensor, multiple, dim=-1, value=0):
    seqlen = tf.shape(tensor)[dim]
    seqlen = tf.cast(seqlen, tf.float32)
    multiple = tf.cast(multiple, tf.float32)
    m = seqlen / multiple
    if tf.math.equal(tf.math.floor(m), m):
        return False, tensor
    remainder = tf.math.ceil(m) * multiple - seqlen
    paddings = tf.zeros([tf.rank(tensor), 2], dtype=tf.int32)
    paddings = tf.expand_dims(paddings, axis=0)  
    paddings = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(paddings, tf.reshape([dim, 1], [1, 2]), tf.reshape([remainder, 0], [1, 2]))
    paddings = tf.squeeze(paddings, axis=0)  
    tensor = tf.pad(tensor, paddings, constant_values=value)
    return True, tensor
```